# Angular 14 Material change background and foreground color in theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14

I'm trying to change the background and the forground color of my theme.
My primary, accent colors are working, but not the background/foreground.

I created a color-palette.scss and added to angular.json

anguarl.json

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css",
      "src/assets/css/themes/charity/color-palette.scss",
      "src/styles.scss"
    ],
```

color-palette.scss

```
/* http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%23607d8b */
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$charity-primary-palette: (
  50 : #fce4ec,
  100 : #f8bcd0,
  200 : #f48fb1,
  300 : #f06292,
  400 : #ec407a,
  500 : #e91e63,
  600 : #e61a5b,
  700 : #e31651,
  800 : #df1247,
  900 : #d90a35,
  A100 : #ffffff,
  A200 : #ffd0d8,
  A400 : #ff9dae,
  A700 : #ff8498,
  contrast: (
    50 : #000000,
    100 : #000000,
    200 : #000000,
    300 : #000000,
    400 : #ffffff,
    500 : #ffffff,
    600 : #ffffff,
    700 : #ffffff,
    800 : #ffffff,
    900 : #ffffff,
    A100 : #000000,
    A200 : #000000,
    A400 : #000000,
    A700 : #000000,
  )
);


$charity-accent-palette: (
  50 : #eceff1,
  100 : #cfd8dc,
  200 : #b0bec5,
  300 : #90a4ae,
  400 : #78919c,
  500 : #607d8b,
  600 : #587583,
  700 : #4e6a78,
  800 : #44606e,
  900 : #334d5b,
  A100 : #abe1ff,
  A200 : #78ceff,
  A400 : #45bcff,
  A700 : #2bb3ff,
  contrast: (
    50 : #000000,
    100 : #000000,
    200 : #000000,
    300 : #000000,
    400 : #000000,
    500 : #ffffff,
    600 : #ffffff,
    700 : #ffffff,
    800 : #ffffff,
    900 : #ffffff,
    A100 : #000000,
    A200 : #000000,
    A400 : #000000,
    A700 : #000000,
  )
);


$charity-warn-palette: (
  50 : #fee8e7,
  100 : #fcc7c3,
  200 : #faa19b,
  300 : #f77b72,
  400 : #f65f54,
  500 : #f44336,
  600 : #f33d30,
  700 : #f13429,
  800 : #ef2c22,
  900 : #ec1e16,
  A100 : #ffffff,
  A200 : #ffe9e9,
  A400 : #ffb8b6,
  A700 : #ff9f9c,
  contrast: (
    50 : #000000,
    100 : #000000,
    200 : #000000,
    300 : #000000,
    400 : #000000,
    500 : #ffffff,
    600 : #ffffff,
    700 : #ffffff,
    800 : #ffffff,
    900 : #ffffff,
    A100 : #000000,
    A200 : #000000,
    A400 : #000000,
    A700 : #000000,
  )
);


$charity-primary: mat.define-palette($charity-primary-palette, 500);
$charity-accent: mat.define-palette($charity-accent-palette, 500);
$charity-warn: mat.define-palette($charity-warn-palette, 500);

$charity-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $charity-primary,
    accent: $charity-accent,
    warn: $charity-warn,
  ),
));

$charity-background-color: #303030;
$charity-foreground-color: #ffffffb3;

$charity-background: map-get($charity-theme, background);
$charity-background: map_merge($charity-background, (background: $charity-background-color));
$charity-theme: map_merge($charity-theme, (background: $charity-background));

$charity-foreground: map-get($charity-theme, foreground);
$charity-foreground: map_merge($charity-foreground, (foreground: $charity-foreground-color));
$charity-theme: map_merge($charity-theme, (foreground: $charity-foreground));

// Emit theme-dependent styles for common features used across multiple components.
@include mat.core-theme($charity-theme);
@include mat.all-component-themes($charity-theme);
```

and I added also the classes "mat-app-background mat-typography" to my body in index.html

Anyone knows what I doing wrong ?

Comment: The line "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css" need to be removed